# C: for loop segmentation fault (core dump)

Tags: c, loops

I don't get why I'm getting a segmentation fault (core dump). I'm just trying to create a program that tells you how many dividers every number has. For example 20, has 6(1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

int NOMBRE, i, RES;
int nbDivis = 0;
printf("Enter a number");
scanf("%d", NOMBRE);

for(i=1; i<= NOMBRE; i++){
    RES = NOMBRE%i;
    if (RES=0)
       nbDivis+= 1;

}
printf("The number of dividers is %d", nbDivis);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `scanf("%d", NOMBRE);` to `scanf("%d",&NOMBRE);`

Comment: Just about *any* book, tutorial or class (even pretty bad ones) should have told you how to use `scanf`, and what the argument types need to be.

Comment: RES = 0 assignment, instead of RES == 0 comparison?

Comment: If you are not **checking the return** of `scanf`, you are not using `scanf` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use `scanf("%d", &NOMBRE);` not `scanf("%d", NOMBRE);`
2. You should use  `if (RES==0)` not `if (RES=0)`

The following `code` could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int NOMBRE;
    int nbDivis = 0;
    printf("Enter a number");
    scanf("%d", &NOMBRE);

    for (int i = 1; i <= NOMBRE; ++i)
        if (NOMBRE%i == 0)
            ++nbDivis;
    printf("The number of dividers is %d", nbDivis);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if the user enters `"one"`? .. and how would you tell? Every answer to a question about using `scanf` should advise that `scanf` cannot be used properly unless you check the return and handle the `EOF` and *matching* and *input* failure cases. I presume you just copied and fixed the pointer issue, but failing to address the return is a missed opportunity and may leave the OP with a false impression on the correct use of `scanf`.

Comment: The question is about the seg fault. You can't explain the whole language in every question. scanf failing to parse its input is another question.